# Initialize static variables declared in header

Tags: c++

I'm changing the class implementation of a large class for a company project that has several static variables declared as private members of the class. There are many arrays and structs declared in the class header that utilize these static variables. I now need to assign the static data members values from my main function somehow. I tried assigning the static variables through the constructor but the header is declared prior to the constructor call so that wasn't possible.

For example, if I have

```
class Data
{
private:
  static unsigned int numReadings = 10;
  static unsigned int numMeters = 4;
  unsigned int array[numMeters];
}
```

I would want to change it such that I could set numReadings and numMeters from my main function somehow, so it will allow all of my arrays and structs that utilize numMeters and numReadings to be initialized properly.

Is there a way to do this in C++? Of course I could always change my class design and set these in the constructor somehow but I'd like to avoid that if I can as it will take quite a long time.

Comment: Global data is evil, but what you're trying to do is transform globaldata (which is evil) to global data modifiable by everyone (which is pure, uncompromising evil). Having said that, it is not clear how your code compiles now given that numMeters is not a constant, and how do you plan it to remain valif if its value will not be even known until run time.

Comment: _"I now need to assign the static data members values from my main function somehow."_ Eh? Why??

Comment: _"I tried assigning the static variables through the constructor"_ You're **fundamentally** misunderstanding basic concepts, including what static variables are. Go back to basics and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: This looks like something you should be using `const` for, not `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making them public and accessing them with Data::numReadings = 10?

UPDATE:

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/*  *   */

class Asdf
{
public:
    static int a;
};

int Asdf::a = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Asdf::a = 2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I got a compiler error. I will post the error here

Comment: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int Data::test"

Comment: You need to put them outside the class header also. I updated my answer.

Comment: It's called the class _definition_.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the accessibility of these variables, you need to define and initialize the static members outside the class definition:

```
// header
class Data
{
private:
  static unsigned int numReadings;
  static unsigned int numMeters;
  unsigned int array[numMeters];  //<=see edit
}; 

// class implementation file
unsigned int Data::numReadings = 10;
unsigned int Data::numMeters = 4;
```

This is part of the implementation of the class and shouldn't be in the header (ODR rule).

Of course, if you want to access these variables (which are shared among all instances of the class) from outside, you need to make them public, or better, foresee and accessor.

**Edit:**

As the question is formulated around the static issue, I didn't notice the variable length array : this is not standard c++, although some compilers might accept it as a non-standard extension.

To do this properly, you should define a vector and initialize it at construction:

```
class Data
{
public: 
  Data ();
private:
  static unsigned int numReadings;
  static unsigned int numMeters;
  vector<unsigned int> mycontainer;       //<=for dynamic size 
}; 

Data::Data() : mycontainer(numMeters) { }  // initialize object with right size
```

Comment: I will try this out. Should I be declaring them this way in the header or implementation file?

Comment: In the implementation file.

Comment: This is still broken. Not sure how you expect `array` to work.

Comment: I get error C2761: 'unsigned int Data::test' : member function redeclaration not allowed

Comment: @TheSalamander: Then you neglected to show us some of your testcase, because this is the first time we've heard of any `Data::test`.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice the array:  variable length arrays is not supported by all the compilers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, I added a test variable declared the same way numReadings is declared as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it **in** the main function, but you can do it in the main.cpp file:

```
// Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "T.h"

using namespace std;

int T::a = 0xff;

int main()
{
   T t; // Prints 255

   return 0;
}

// T.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class T {
public:
    T() { cout << a << endl; }

private:
    static int a;
};
```

Comment: Well, if the static member is accessible, properly initialized in the class implementation file, he could change the value whereever it's needed (although doing it with a writer function would be cleaner), no ?

Comment: @Christophe: I really don't know, because it's private to T I think only T can access it. The better way would be to add a `static void T::setA(int a);` to the class.

Comment: I agree, that's what I meant with "writer function".